# Discover last time a Google vertex ai endpoints was called

Tags: google-cloud-platform, endpoint, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Is it possible to discover the last time a Google vertex ai endpoints was called. Ran describe on one, it does not provide the needed information.
Our goal is to discover vertex ai endpoints that have not been trigger in x days.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to track `Vertex AI endpoints` last API call through Cloud Monitoring as metrics of Vertex AI are being exported.

You can apply these API calls to request information regarding your desired endpoints.

```
httpRequest.protocol="HTTP/1.1"
-- labels."appengine.googleapis.com/instance_name"=""
-- labels."appengine.googleapis.com/instance_name"=""
 labels."appengine.googleapis.com/instance_name"=""
```

Make sure that you have set the appropriate [roles and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface#getting_started).

Comment: Which google API is that used with? I under stand the parameters, but I don't know which monitoring API, and what format.